# Using System User Name to grant permission

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a global function that gets the current users ID. It works file. Now I want to compare that to a list of users in a table that I want to have access to the program.
My table is Tbl_Staff
The field that holds that values for each person is UserID
My Function is called GetUserName
Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim Message         As String
Dim Currentdb       As DAO.Database
Dim RecSet          As DAO.Recordset

Set RecSet = Currentdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Tbl_Staff WHERE [Tbl_Staff].[UserID] = UserName())

If UserName = RecSet Then

Exit Sub

    Else

        Message = MsgBox("You do not have permission to access this database." & vbCrLf & "Please contact Robert Smith for access", vbOKOnly)

    DoCmd.CloseDatabase
    End If

End Sub
```

I am really stuck. Thank you

Comment: If the recordset's `EOF` property is True then there's no matching user

Comment: Think next about your form now having two functions, some people get A or B or both

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim RecSet As DAO.Recordset

    Set RecSet = Application.Currentdb.OpenRecordset( _
       "SELECT * FROM Tbl_Staff WHERE [Tbl_Staff].[UserID] = '" & UserName() & "'")

    If RecSet.EOF Then
        MsgBox "You do not have permission to access this database." & _
                vbCrLf & "Please contact Robert Smith for access"

        DoCmd.CloseDatabase
    End If

End Sub
```

Might need to tweak the SQL to account for differences in case between the username in the DB and the return value from UserName()

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. Worked like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, use the access built-in function

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim blnUserExist As Boolean
    blnUserExist = Nz(DCount("*", "Tbl_Staff", "UserID='" & Environ("username") & "'"),0)

    If blnUserExist = False Then
        MsgBox "You do not have permission to access this database." & vbCrLf & "Please contact Robert Smith for access", vbOKOnly
        DoCmd.Quit
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Santosh. I have used Environ many times. I have been reading though that it is not always reliable. The suggestion that Tim gave worked great.

Comment: @Tiny1127 Choice is your but typically I would go with this if I am writing code in MS-Access. `Environ(username)` was just a suggestion and you could replace this with your GetUserName function.